# Spring MVC test post method with controller redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot, mocking

I have a test:

```
@Test
public void shouldAddCompany() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/companies")
            .param("name", "companyName"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("company",
                    hasProperty("name", is("companyName"))));

}
```

and my controller method looks like that:

```
@PostMapping("/companies")
public String displayCompaniesPost(@ModelAttribute Company company) {
    companyService.save(company);
    return "redirect:/companies";
}
```

How can i check company attribute in test? There is a problem because of redirect and status 302.

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'company'
 Expected: hasProperty("name", is "companyName")
 but: was null
```

I think it occurs because controller is going to GET method because of redirection. When I remove this redirection everything is ok, but I don't want to remove that redirection.

EDIT (GetMapping):

```
@GetMapping({"/", "/companies"})
public String displayCompanies(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("company", new Company());
    List<Company> companies = companyService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("companies", companies);
    return "companies";
}
```

I thought the problem is because of addding attribute with the same name in getMapping, but when I removed it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us what the controller method for the path you're redirecting too looks like (`@GetMapping("/companies")`)?

Comment: @Ben Ok, i've edited first post. I thought the problem is because of addding attribute with the same name in getMapping, but when I removed it, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: your test is expecting the Companies attribute to have name `"companyName"` but in the GET you're adding a new `Company` which i assume doesn't have a name. Your test should probably be looking for `companies` as that is the attribute being returned by the controller method you're redirecting to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your approach. If you POST to a controller method, and it returns a Redirect you will have no ability to access any model information set by that controller, it just returns an HTTP 302 with a Location Header to the client telling it the new url to go to (in this case `GET /companies`). If this is a strictly Unit test, that is the extent of what you can test for this method.

I would consider instead treating this as an integration test, and  change your test to have two separate steps:

1. POST `/companies` and validate that the response is the expected redirect
2. GET `/companies` and validate that the list of companies returned contains the new company you posted in step 1

Comment: Ok, but when I post /companies, it will create new company in my database. Should I create a new db for tests or what?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm suggesting, if you want to an effect of the method that isn't exposed via it's interface, you're going to need to test using a datastore. This is a great usage of in-memory databases like h2